# Jenkins selenium grid hub refuses incoming selenium Node connections from external IP's

Tags: selenium, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, selenium-grid2

I have a Selenium Grid hub running on Jenkins using the Selenium Plugin. 
I have a Selenium grid node running on the same machine and it is successfully connected to the Hub. 
From an external machine i cant't seem to ping the 4444 port on which hub is running through Jenkins. 
I can ping the port, if Hub is started separately through command line. 
I have Firewalls disabled on both my machines so its not a network issue.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role node -hub http://<IP>:4444/grid/register -timeout 10000 -browserTimeout 10000 -sessionMaxIdleTimeInSeconds 10000
```

`16:34:58.122 INFO - Launching a Selenium Grid node
16:34:59.982 WARN - error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.Connect to <IP>:4444 [<IP>] failed: Connection refused: connect
16:35:00.029 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.51-b03
16:35:00.029 INFO - OS: Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64
16:35:00.044 INFO - v2.46.0, with Core v2.46.0. Built from revision 87c69e2
16:35:00.107 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
16:35:00.107 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
16:35:00.154 INFO - Version Jetty/5.1.x
16:35:00.154 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
16:35:00.154 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@76a4d6c
16:35:00.154 INFO - Started HttpContext[/wd,/wd]
16:35:00.154 INFO - Started HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]
16:35:00.154 INFO - Started HttpContext[/,/]
16:35:00.154 INFO - Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:5555
16:35:00.154 INFO - Started org.openqa.jetty.jetty.Server@1f7030a6
16:35:00.154 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
16:35:00.185 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
16:35:00.200 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://<IP>/grid/register
16:35:01.232 INFO - Couldn't register this node: Error sending the registration request: Connect to <IP>:4444 [IP] failed: Connection refused: connect
16:35:07.232 INFO - Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Connect to <IP>:4444 [IP] failed: Connection refused: connect`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the HUB has Max connection limit set and you have already reached the connection Limit.

You can simply debug it by shutdown the HUB and restart the hub and register the node you are trying to the HUB. Hope it will register .

Must be the Connection Limit as if you don't supply anything i think a HUB can handle 5 instances.

Please try and share your reply

Comment: I tried but doesn't seem to help. There are no other nodes connected to the hub.

Comment: Can you telnet.ping the system port ..... in the HUB try netstat -an and verify port listening or not.